# Navigation bar appearing under under Navigation bar?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I added a Navigation bar to my view controller, I noticed when I ran my app the navigation bar was being cut off by the status bar. I added a positioning function to my code but I encountered a weird problem. The navigation bar that I created appears underneath a blank navigation bar.
[image: navigation bar under navigation bar]
[image: Navigation bar Constraints]

Here is my code from the viewcontoller.swift file

```
import UIKit

class myaccountViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationBarDelegate, UIBarPositioningDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var navbr: UINavigationBar!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navbr.delegate = self
}

func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
    return.topAttached
}

}
```

I do not want to embed a navigation controller into it.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a navigation controller? It will make this much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

try to add top constraint to view not to TopLayout guide.
Seems like your all constraints are relative to margin. Remove constraint to margin. add them to view.

Comment: Doesn't work, my navigation bar doesn't display at all.

Comment: Do you mean superview or view?

Comment: constraints to superview.